# Куда проматывается страница?

Tags: веб-программирование

Куда проматывается страница - вверх или вниз?
Я мотаю на телефоне, проводя пальцем снизу вверх, а на экране ноутбука мотаю колесом мыши сверху вниз. Содержимое на экране уходит вверх, словно бы экран уходит вниз по содержимому страницы. Как правильно это называть? Относительно каких ориентиров определять - вниз я мотаю или вверх?
Например, один мой друг просит меня "Промотай вверх", другой, имея в виду то же самое, просит "Промотай вниз немного". Дак всё-таки:
Как это корректно определять?

Comment: Данный вопрос не соответствует тематике SO.

Comment: Относительно текущего отображемого куска страницы. Если новый отображаемый кусок после прокрутки находится ниже старого куска, отображавшегося перед прокруткой, - значит вниз. Если выше - значит вверх. (примечание: я не толковый словарь и просто озвучил своё собственное понимание, использовать на свой страх и риск)

Comment: Но вопрос скорее всего и правда не очень по тематике